# Set-SPSiteUrl : Url {0} already in use!

Tags: site-collection, host-header, host-named

Why is the script below giving me the error that the url {0} already in use?

```
Set-SPSiteUrl (Get-SPSite "http://nonsecuresiteurl") -Url 'https://securesiteurl' -Zone Extranet
```

> Set-SPSiteUrl : Url {0} already in use!

Doing a `Get-SPSiteurl -identity "http://nonsecuresiteurl"` gives me this:

```
Url                                                                         Zone
---                                                                         ----
http://nonsecuresiteurl/                                                    Default
```

How can I add a new zone to the Site collection using a host name?

Comment: what happen when you browse the site collection with https in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be used in another content database. Check in which content database the site is created and check if it exists in other content databases.

Comment: That was it. It existed in another content database.